# Git - committing changes in master to a new branch

Tags: git, version-control, branching-strategy

**Scenario**

I have a solution, cloned to my local machine, and I have made a few changes to the master branch *(but I have **not** committed them yet)*.

**Problem**

The work isn't finished, so I want to commit these changes into their own branch for the time being, but I've been working in master.

How can I commit changes in master to their own branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be on the safe side, [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your work first, then create your branch:

```
git stash
git checkout -b newbranch
git stash pop
# work, add and commit in newbranch
git checkout master
# resume working on master
```

Comment: I don't think there's any need for the stash, checking out a new branch with a base of the current branch won't modify the working copy. `git checkout -b  newbranch` alone should be sufficient, if it's not in what way is it not-safe?

Comment: I agree, but I always prefer to save first, then try stuff. Especially here, where those are not my files ;)